# What typeface is used in this magazine?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I found this beautiful **Bon Appetit** [magazine](http://www.ccbuckley.com/print-1/130x4rzyjgu7tzzdeocs7gqg5pv0j8) (it's an iPad magazine). But I couldn't quite identify the font used :

[image: ![black and white]
[image: ![other]
[image: features]
[image: contents]
[image: Editor's letter]

I've tried [Fontspring Matcherator](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator), [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) & [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/).. The closest typefaces are [Thorowgood](http://www.myfonts.com/search/Thorowgood+/) and [Poster Display Monster](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/textaxis/poster/display-monster/) , but it's not quite the right answer. The contrast between the thicks and the thins is not as pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your images next to the word 'content' written in the thorowgood font you can clearly see this is the same font, the creator just played around with the height and width of the font.

[image]

Comment: It's very, *very* similar but you can see its *not* the same font. The stroke contrast is very different, the "s" is significantly different, the counters are different sizes etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Austin Ultra from [Commercial Type](https://commercialtype.com/catalog/austin_and_austin_news/austin/austin/ultra).

Comment: It's still not the right one

Comment: When suggesting a font please include a screenshot.